# C# Program that imports large datasets running in 32bit

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I have inherited a C# application that imports very large data sets.  We are getting some out of memory issues and I think the problem is that the program is running as 32bit vs 64bit.  The application is on a 64bit server and setup as a windows scheduled task.

I found that the test and production release have the 32bit preferred checked.  This solution has about 7 projects.  I was going to try to uncheck the 32bit preferred checkbox, but will I need to do these to each of the other projects that this might be using a reference?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: By all means, if you're running out of memory, try running as 64-bit. Note though that you'll need more memory overall since pointers are now twice as large. The exact amount of additional memory depends on the nature of your application, but 20% has been my experience. If you have data structures with lots of pointers, it could be more.

Comment: Rather than wonder: IMO, just change it to be explicitly x64 rather than Any. If any of the libraries are incompatible: it'll tell you right away when you try to build. Also: if the problem is large single managed arrays: this may not help by itself - even with very-large-object support enabled, there are still some limits on vector sizes. This is particularly relevant to `byte[]`, which is relevant to what @Dai says below.

Comment: It sounds like you're reading an entire file into-memory. You _probably_ don't need to do that; why can't you read the file in buffer-sized chunks?

Comment: Doe all the projects in the solution need to have this unchecked as well?  I think the server memory is at 16gb.

Comment: @MarcGravell "If any of the libraries are incompatible: it'll tell you right away when you try to build" - since when `csc` done that? Otherwise we'd never get 64 vs 32-bit errors at assembly load-time.

Comment: @Dai um... I had that literally this week - complaining of an architecture mismatch between libraries, that I resolved by switching from Any to x64. I'm not saying it is foolproof, but: it does try.

Comment: The executable project's settings regulate the bittedness of the process (see linked question).

Comment: Re "all projects": just the executable process should be fine. That is what has the PE header (on windows, at least), which is what determines how it gets launched by the OS

Comment: I figured out why nothing was working.  The TFS CI build process was had a setting for 32bit.  That overwrote whatever I did in the visual studio solution.  After changing the TFS Build process, It runs as 64bit.